# Is there any other option to draw multiple routes in mapbox?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I m using **MGLPolyline** to draw multiple routes. But its not give me route selection(tap) option.

My code :

```
 // Convert the route’s coordinates into a polyline.
    var routeCoordinates = route.coordinates!
    let routeLine = MGLPolyline(coordinates: &routeCoordinates, count: route.coordinateCount)

 // Add the polyline to the map and fit the viewport to the polyline.
    homeMapView.addAnnotation(routeLine)
    homeMapView.setVisibleCoordinates(&routeCoordinates, count: route.coordinateCount, edgePadding: .zero, animated: true)
```

Comment: Could you share how you are retrieving the routes? Are you using the Mapbox Directions or Navigation SDKs?

Comment: I m using mapbox direction sdk.

Comment: func drawRoute(route: Route) {
        // Convert the route’s coordinates into a polyline.
        var routeCoordinates = route.coordinates!
        let routeLine = MGLPolyline(coordinates: &routeCoordinates, count: route.coordinateCount)

        // Add the polyline to the map and fit the viewport to the polyline.
        homeMapView.addAnnotation(routeLine)
        homeMapView.setVisibleCoordinates(&routeCoordinates, count: route.coordinateCount, edgePadding: .zero, animated: true)
        homeMapView.add(routeLine)
    }

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MapboxDirections.swift, set [`includesAlternativeRoutes`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-navigation-ios/directions/0.15.1/Classes/RouteOptions.html#/c:@M@MapboxDirections@objc(cs)MBRouteOptions(py)includesAlternativeRoutes) to true. The request for routes should then return an multiple route objects.

Retrieve the routes, then use them to draw route lines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have already set includesAlternativeRoutes to true. And I m able to draw multiple routes. But my issue is with route selection.  I can't able to select(choose) single routes from multiple routes. I want to select single route and navigate to turn by turn navigation view.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to set your mapView delegate to self and use the folllowing code:

```
func navigationMapView(_ mapView: NavigationMapView, didSelect route: Route) {
        // Select your route here 
        self.currentRoute = route

        }
```